# Jquery Image Fade Lightbox-Like/Effect Stutter in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, image-scaling

So I hand-made my own lightbox-like effect and I've run into a little bit of a problem on Firefox.  In Chrome, the fade-in looks clean and smooth. And IE, well lets just say I have a conditional statement that opts out of the code if the user is browsing in IE.

Firefox looks a bit stuttered, but I'm pretty sure the image is loaded properly.

So I am wondering if there is a way to smooth these types of things out?
My code looks something like this for the click function, although I dont know if this will be of much help.

```
    $main_image.click(function(){                           
        $lightbox_panel.fadeIn(fadeTime);
    })
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

About all you can do (from my experience at least) is add more time to the transition.  FF is just a little slow when it comes to these things.

Comment: I understand where your coming from, I just know that the lightbox plug-in doesn't seem to stutter so much.  It could also be that the images i'm playing with are much bigger in resolution and jquery is having to resize them as well?  Given that the resizing is done before the fade in

Comment: you could possibly write your own function too so you can have control over that.  If all you need is fade and resize it shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: Well that is the problem.  My handwritten resizing function seems to be somewhat subpar apparently ;)

Comment: can you post it on pastebin.com or jsfiddle.net so I can take a look?

Comment: Thank you but I simply switched up the order so the div loads first and then the image, this seems to look more smooth.  Appreciate the comments though guys!